# How to balance remaining %?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

The Hadoop HDFS Balancer can balance usage % among nodes.  However, I couldn't find a way to balance remaining % (i.e. empty space %).

E.g. Let's say I have 3 nodes, with 2 dedicated to HDFS and 1 with other shared disk usage.  The balancer will balance the usage % among the 3 nodes.  As such, the shared node will always run out of disk space first because it has other files on disk.

What I want is to balance the remaining disk space %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wiki page explains how to reserve non DFS usage per data node.
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/DiskSetup